# How to create hanging bullet?

Tags: margins, indentation

How can I create 'hanging bullet' (**bullet in margin**) followed with text. I would like to put it in `\newcommand` but I'm not managing to do it. I tried this:

```
\newcommand{\question}[2]{\\[0.5cm]\hspace{-4.5cm}\bullet\textbf{#1}\\[0.2cm]\hspace{5mm}\text{#2}\\}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve. I think you may want to use `\llap`:

```
\leavevmode\llap{$\bullet$ short text }Normal text here
```

(The `\leavevmode` is needed to start the paragraph.)

Comment: Ok, is it possible to put `\llap{$\bullet$ short text}this-text` **this-text beside** bullet and short-text? **Not underneath**, please.

Comment: Nvm, I added `\vspace{-12pt}`... It looks fine.

Comment: @an_ant: I'm really sorry, I acted against my own principles and didn't test my answer before posting. Nevertheless, it would be good if add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/1235) to your question; it's really hard to see what exactly you aim at.

Answer (score 4):

Since it looks like you want this to be an environment, why not use the enumitem package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{question}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[question]{label=\textbullet,labelindent=-.5in,leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=.25in}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{question}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item another item
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can mark up code sections by indenting with four spaces or using the '101010' button in the editing window.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this out.  I tried the 101010 button, but it only made the first line of my pasted example code.  So it seems like its easier just to insert the <pre><code> .. </pre></code> tags manually, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: don't you want proper nesting? <pre><code> ... </code></pre>? ;-)  Also, I didn't know about lipsum.  Thanks!

Comment: Just highlight the code before hitting the button.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt to shift the bullet into the margin with a negative `\hspace` didn't work because it inserts glue.  When TeX breaks your paragraph into lines, it discards the glue at the beginning of the line, so you end up with a line `\hbox` that starts with the bullet character.

I replaced your `\hspace{-4.5cm}` with `\llap{\textbullet}`.  That generates a zero-width `\hbox` inside your paragraph.  That generated `\hbox` contains `\hss` followed by `\textbullet`.  When TeX breaks the paragraph into lines, the generated `\hbox` is *not* discarded, but is placed at the beginning of the line.

[The `\hss` has natural width of 0, but shrinks by the size of the `\textbullet` (so the `\hbox` can stay zero-width).  It "backspaces" by the size of the bullet into the left margin.  The bullet is set, bringing us back to "beginning" of the line (the reference point) and then the text "Question?" is set.]

```
\loggingall
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\question}[2]{\\[0.5cm]\hspace{-4.5cm}\textbullet\textbf{#1}\\[0.2cm]\hspace{5mm}\textrm{#2}\\}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\question{Question?}{Answer.}

This is also a test.
\showlists
\vfil
\pagebreak[4]
\renewcommand{\question}[2]{\\[0.5cm]\llap{\textbullet}\textbf{#1}\\[0.2cm]\textrm{#2}\\}
This is a test.
\question{Question?}{Answer.}

This is also a test.
\showlists
\end{document}
```

Note 1: I changed `\text` to `\textrm` in your macro.

Note 2: This is my first attempt at an answer, so it's highly likely that I didn't solve the problem with good LaTeX style.  I thought I might learn something by trying to give an answer.  (I did!)  I hope the rest of the community will be forgiving of whatever stupid errors I committed.

Comment: I marked your inline code with backticks.

Comment: @Hendrik: thank you.  In addition to being a TeX novice, I'm a StackExchange novice too! It looks much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This tricky solution is taken from the TexBook. It defines the command `\marginalbullet` that can be used anywhere inside a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=10pt
\def\strutdepth{\dp\strutbox}
\def\specialbullet{\vtop to \strutdepth{
  \baselineskip\strutdepth
  \vss\llap{$\bullet$ }\null}}
\def\marginalbullet{\strut\vadjust{\kern-\strutdepth\specialbullet}}
\begin{document}
Text before \marginalbullet \lipsum[1]\par\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```