# position symbol horizontally

Tags: positioning

I would like to place symbol `\ding{97}` directly at the constant distance from the headword. I made command to place the symbol

```
% place frequent star
\newcommand{\freqstar}[1]{\hspace*{-1em}{\color{darkgreen}{\ding{97}}}}
```

in front of the headword. For placing the headwords I use this command

```
\newcommand\entry[3][]{\hangpara{2em}{1}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{{#2}}}}\#3\ifx\relax#1\relax\markboth{#2}{#2}\else\markboth{#1}{#1}\fi\par}\nopagebreak[4]
```

Problem is that the position is not precise. I would like to achieve that headwords are placed exactly same and the symbol is in front of them.

Follows a picture of incorrect placement:
[image: symbol placement]

Comment: You should make a *complete* example that demonstrates your problem so that people don't have to track down the packages your are using before being able to do some tests.

Comment: Thank you for remark. I will always put the minimum example.

Comment: Why the argument `#1` if you don't use any?

Comment: Thats true. I can delete it. I copy the structure from working command and left the field with no reason.

Comment: similar topic: [How to create hanging bullet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7865/) has quite a bit of commentary (although i think the answer here is a better fit for the current question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macro `\llap` can be used to print something to the left without changing the current position:

```
\newcommand{\freqstar}{% without argument
  \leavevmode % stars paragraph if necessary, \llap does not do this
  \llap{%
    \textcolor{darkgreen}{\ding{97}}%
    \,% space between symbol and entry
  }%
}%
```

With lowering:

```
\newcommand{\freqstar}{% without argument
  \leavevmode % stars paragraph if necessary, \llap does not do this
  \llap{%
    \raisebox{-.2ex}{%
      \textcolor{darkgreen}{\ding{97}}%
    }%
    \,% space between symbol and entry
  }%
}%
```

Centered around the math axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}

\newcommand{\freqstar}{%
  \leavevmode % stars paragraph if necessary, \llap does not do this
  \llap{%
    $%
      \setlength{\mathsurround}{0pt}%
      \vcenter{%
        \hbox{%
          \textcolor{darkgreen}{\ding{97}}%
        }%
      }%
    $%
    \,% space between symbol and entry
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\freqstar \textbf{\ae}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. It works as wished - except that I need to lower the position of symbol now.

Comment: Excellent and beautifull :) !!! Merry Christmas dear community.

Comment: How is `\vcenter` defined? If I am not mistaken it is a tex primitive, right?

Comment: @azetina Yes. it is a TeX primitive.