# Margin note between columns

Tags: two-column, marginpar, marginnote

I am looking for a way to place a simple "margin" note right beside the start of a paragraph in a two-column text. As it is right now, it just appears at either the left or right margin.

The note is just a number separated from the text, because otherwise it messes up the separation of words in a line (which matters in the text I am working on, not in the example below).

See this sample code below (see what I'm looking for in the image):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\reversemarginpar

\marginnote{1.} \lipsum[1]

\marginnote{2.} \lipsum[1]

\marginnote{3.} \lipsum[1]

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Move the number 3. over to the start of right paragraph, between the columns.]

Comment: If you are happy with the 3 appearing in the right margin (instead of between the two columns), you can use the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101553/margin-notes-on-both-left-and-right).

Comment: Or a slightly more automated version [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226847/making-marginnote-to-appear-either-side-of-twocolumn-twoside-document)

Comment: No. My intention was to have the three right beside the beginning line of each new paragraph, to the left. In this case, the 1. left of the first Lorem; the 2. left of the second Lorem; and the 3. left of the third Lorem, and between columns.

Comment: Is the note always a number? (So not very wide?)  Instead of `\marginpar{3. }...`, try `\leavevmode\llap{3. }\lipsum[1]`. (For more of the same, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7865/how-to-create-hanging-bullet )

Comment: If the numbering is always consecutive, you can also use `titlesec` to number the paragraphs with paragraph numbers that hangs to the left.

Comment: Perfect! The `titlesec` package has worked, and for anyone interested I will be posting here the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, achieved by `\llap`ing a string of numbers so that they hang out to the left of the paragraph.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}

\newcounter{parnum}
\newcommand*\NumPar{\refstepcounter{parnum}\leavevmode\llap{\arabic{parnum}. }}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\NumPar \lipsum[1-2]

\NumPar \lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]

\NumPar \lipsum[5]

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works very well, too, and does not require using an additional package like I ended up using in my solution (thanks to your suggestion). Thanks!

Comment: I just tried your implementation in my document, and it's perfect. However, is there a way to make the paragraph label/counter reset at the start of every `\section`? I would prefer to avoid a carry-over from the last one, if possible.

Comment: You can [use the `\counterwithin` command](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-addtoreset), like so: `\counterwithin{parnum}{section}`. This command is available in newer TeX engines; for older releases you may need to load the `chngcntr` package.

Comment: (Incidentally, since I called `\refstepcounter` to increment the markers, you can also use `\label` and `\ref` to refer to them as usual.)

Comment: Where would you put that command, then? First define `\newcounter{parnum}` and _then_ write `\counterwithin{parnum}{section}` the line below?

Comment: Yes, I'd put it there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user Willie Wong's help, the question is solved. Using the `titlesec` package, and by adding the following line of code, every new paragraph is labeled as I desired:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\normalfont}{}{}{}
```

This is so long as the new paragraph is started with `\paragraph{title/label here}`, of course.

My previous example, with the implementation (see the attached image for result):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\normalfont}{}{}{}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\reversemarginpar

\paragraph{1.} \lipsum[1]

\paragraph{2.} \lipsum[1]

\paragraph{3.} \lipsum[1]

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Labeled paragraphs]